# WebSphere Application Server 7.0 with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, websphere

Where can I find a working WebSphere Application Server 7.0 plugin for Eclipse v2023.09?

Thanks!

I tried installing the IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5x Developer Tools plugin, but it does not include the WAS7.0 version.

Comment: There won't be one. WAS 7 is out of support and Eclipse 2023.09 is one of the most recent eclipse releases.